How can I extract nested select statements from a query using SQLFluff?
I have the following example SQL (it gets more complex):
select
    *
from
    (select
        a,
        b
    from
        agents)

I want to parse such a string using sqlfluff
from sqlfluff.core import Parser
p = Parser(dialect='ansi')
parsed = p.parse_string(query)

and split the query into two parts (and ideally into two trees/ParsedString), the outer one and the inner one. The inner query should be inserted into a CTAS statement and the outer query should reference it.
Expected pseudocode:
outer_tree.set_innermost_token('reagents')
inner_tree.set_outermost_tokens('create or replace reagents as')
print(outer_tree.generate_SQL())
# !!! for simplicity I am removing the indentation
# select * from reagents
print(inner_tree.generate_SQL())
# !!! for simplicity I am removing the indentation
# create or replace reagents as select a, b from agents

Please bear in mind, this is just a simple example, I know a rudimentary regexp could help in this cases, however, I am aiming to modify more complex queries. Additionally, the SQL queries are already written, therefore I cannot go about writing only a generator.
I looked at the cli.py and also on the internals of Linter, but I could only generate the same SQL code as was provided (by setting the variable filtered_source_patches to None on line 222).

You're correct that you can get the parsed structure by using the Parser class, but you may find the parse_string() method on the Linter class more useful. Once you've got the parsed object, you can use recursive_crawl to look for segments of a certain type. In the following example we search for select_statement segments, and you can see we find the two (with one nested inside the other).
from sqlfluff.core import Linter

# Whitespace removed for brevity
input_sql = "select * from (select a, b from agents)"

parsed = Linter(dialect="ansi").parse_string(input_sql)
print("File:", parsed.tree.raw)
# File: select * from (select a, b from agents)
for idx, outer_select in enumerate(parsed.tree.recursive_crawl("select_statement")):
    print("Inner:", idx, outer_select.raw)
# Inner: 0 select * from (select a, b from agents)
# Inner: 1 select a, b from agents

It sounds like you want to generate a CREATE TABLE statement from the inner ones, which you could do by simple string manipulation. Replacing the content within the outer SQL is a little harder, but you could leverage the position information stored in the pos_marker attribute of the outer_segment variable above to find out where in the outer file it is to do some string manipulation.
